# Display Product Name in Magento Transactional Email(magento 1.9x)

Tags: magento-1.9

[image]I want to display product name only product name in magento transactional email, but using 
 {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
whole product grid comes like qty sku total etc. i only want to display product name

Comment: Do you want to remove the other columns like qty, total etc.?

Comment: yes that could also work for me

Comment: Then what is your requirement?

Comment: i want only product name that have been ordered

Comment: Can you share any screenshot what do you want? As if you want only product name then remove the other columns.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnNbf.jpg added i only want ordered product name

Comment: Can you accept the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto below path:

> /app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/email/order/items.phtml

and replace the code with below code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     base_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2006-2017 X.commerce, Inc. and affiliates (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
?>
<?php $_order = $this->getOrder() ?>
<?php if ($_order): ?>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_order->getAllItems() as $_item): ?>
    <?php if($_item->getParentItem()) continue; else $i++; ?>
    <tbody<?php echo $i%2 ? ' bgcolor="#F6F6F6"' : '' ?>>
        <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
    </tbody>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

</table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If you don't have items.phtml on your theme then copy it from base and then edit.

And Goto below path:

> /app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml

and replace the code with below code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     base_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2006-2017 X.commerce, Inc. and affiliates (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
?>
<?php $_item = $this->getItem() ?>
<?php $_order = $this->getItem()->getOrder() ?>
<tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px; border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;">
        <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

If you don't have items.phtml on your theme then copy it from base and then edit.

Comment: i tried your solution qty price gone but table heading and total still comes https://imgur.com/a/BVlAjll

Comment: Table headers are coming from items.phtml. May be any extension override that file. Enable the template path hint and send one email from admin then you will get the exact path of that file.

Comment: no cant find whats overriding

Comment: Did you enable template path hints? What is the template path showing on mail?

Comment: i enabled but nothing showing their

Comment: Can you give me the screenshot what you are getting?